# React await for data fetch with axios to happen before triggering next line is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

here's a brief overview of my component OneRoadmap: in async componentDidMount, I am first calling "await this.props.getRoadmaps", which is an action in my Redux, this action will send a get request to my api which will retrieve items from my database, then, from those items retrieved, we send a dispatch to the Reducer, calling GET_ROADMAPS, this is done like

```
export const getRoadmaps = () => dispatch => {
dispatch(setRoadmapsLoading());
axios
.get("/api/roadmaps")
.then(res => dispatch({ type: GET_ROADMAPS, payload: res.data }));
};
```

and my component looks like:

```
async componentDidMount() {
await this.props.getRoadmaps();
var location1 = this.props.location.pathname;
var n = location1.slice(9);

var current_roadmaps = this.props.roadmap.roadmaps;

this.displayRoadmap = current_roadmaps.filter(
  eachRoadmap => eachRoadmap._id == n
);
// now we have a roadmap

this.setState({
  treeData: this.displayRoadmap[0].roadmap[0],
  loading: false
});
}
```

GET_ROADMAPS will update my Redux state.

The problem appears to be: **await this.props.getRoadmaps() will only wait until getRoadmaps() sends the dispatch to GET_ROADMAPS, which means it doesn't wait until GET_ROADMAPS update the redux state**, this means few lines later, when I do this.props.roadmap.roadmaps, it is going to be undefined because this.props.roadmap.roadmaps is probably called before the GET_ROADMAPS finish updating my redux state.

Please guide me if there are any ways to solve to problem :) and please correct me if the problem is not what I think it is.

P.S. I referenced https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data, this info on there will usually work but it appears to be that since I have an extra dispatch to my redux store, the dispatch updates the store after I call this.props.roadmap.roadmaps, which means I get undefined and can't use that variable in my rendering

Comment: Can you please post the full `getRoadmaps` function. It should be async as well, or you need to do `return axios.get(...).then(...)`

Comment: sorry about that, I updated my question and I will go change my code to what you suggested

Comment: I think it is returned with the arrow function

Comment: No, since you put it in a block you have to return explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you’re not returning in your action creator.  You have to explicitly return when you create a block (use curly braces).

Return your axios call and it should work properly.